# addClass when the screen resolution is less than 767px in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap menu, I need to add some classes and attributes when the screen resolution is less than 767 px. My code:

```
<li class="item-104 deeper parent">
  <a href="#">О министерстве</a>
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-113"><a href="#">Новости</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-134"><a href="#">Подразделения Министерства</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-135 deeper parent">
        <a href="#">Подведомственные учреждение министерства</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                <li class="item-159"><a href="#">ФОК «ЖАР» МВД Республики Узбекистан</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-136"><a href="#">Прием на службу в органы внутренних дел</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-177"><a href="#">Тендеры</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).resize(function(){
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if(windowWidth < 767)$(".navbar-nav ul").addClass("dropdown-menu") && $(".navbar-nav li",".navbar-nav ul").removeClass("parent","nav-child");
      });
    });
</script>
```

and I want to add the attribute data-toggle="dropdown" to the link which has a subdirectory with ul, i.e. `<li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><ul><li>` etc.

Comment: You can easily achieve this kind of request without JavaScript, if you use @media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @Roberrrt could show in my example how to do it?

Comment: Ofcourse! Let me write some code ;)!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with `&&` between

`$(".navbar-nav ul").addClass("dropdown-menu")` and `$(".navbar-nav li",".navbar-nav ul").removeClass("parent","nav-child");`

Instead it should be like this

```
if (windowWidth < 767) {
      $(".navbar-nav ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");
      $(".navbar-nav li", ".navbar-nav ul").removeClass("parent", "nav-child");
    }
```

Also this same thing can be achieved using CSS media queries

Comment: my resize (jquery code) is triggered when the user changes the screen resolution, is it possible to know the width of the screen and looking at it to add a class and remove?

Answer (score 2):

**Mediaqueries** (as requested as an alternative)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-color: #FF0;
  }
}
```

This example changes the background-color of the body to yellow whenever the screen screen is *less* than 800 pixels.

**How do you apply this in your case?**

Apply all classes you wish to use beforehand, and wrap the markup of the classes that need to invoke in media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .dropdown-menu {
    /* CSS that invokes the dropdown */
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .nav-child {
    /* CSS that is being used in medium / large screens */
  }
}
```

Comment: ooh no... i know this ))) I just wanted to remove unnecessary classes and add new ones instead